# Load next id with mouse scrolling

Tags: jquery

I have four `id` for four different `section`. And I included all this code in `index.html`. I used `jQuery` to `show` only 1 `id` and hiding the other 3 `id`s. Now I want to get this effect with mouse scrolling. That means, when my scrolling position reached to the bottom then the next `id` should appear and previous `id` should disappear.

I have been trying for 4 days but could not. you can check the live demo [here](http://hoxdevelopment.com/comming_soon/index.html) and you can download the template [here](http://hoxdevelopment.com/comming_soon.rar)

*if some one who is expert, your guideline will reach me to the point. -thanks in advance*

Comment: you want to show nearby id of the mouse position to visible and other's to hide ? and near by relative to what, top/bottom or there is any need of comparison like more near by id is visible and other's not

Comment: near by relative to bottom when scrolling-bottom and near by relative to top when scrolling-up

Comment: and maintly you want wheel or with scrollbar ?

Comment: I want it with wheel